# What is the difference between edit field and textfield blackberry

Tags: blackberry, textfield, blackberry-editfield

I want to know in what way these field components are different.. Though `EditField` is the class derived from `TextField`, why was it done.. what are the extra features provided in `EditField`..

I can not make out the answer from the documentations and usage..

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for editfield it says,

> An editable text field specifically designed for characters entered by holding a key while rolling the trackwheel.

- Behaviour

> Adds the ability to hold down a letter and roll to get related characters. The actual characters selected will be based on locale.
>
> Rolling wraps around the list of available characters, once one end of the list is reached.